# Allowing user to click only one "."

Tags: javascript, replace, calculator

I am trying to implement a simple javascript-html calculator. What i want to do is,typing only one '.' by the user. How can i control this ? Here is the code that i tried.

I can already find the number of '.' but i'am confused now also this replaceAll function is not replacing '.' with empty string.

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replace)
{
    //if replace is null, return original string otherwise it will
    //replace search string with 'undefined'.
    if(!replace) 
        return this;

    return this.replace(new RegExp('[' + search + ']', 'g'), replace);
};
function calculate(){
    var value = document.calculator.text.value;
    var valueArray = value.split("");
    var arrayLenght = valueArray.length;
    var character = ".";
    var charCount = 0;
    for(i=0;i<arrayLenght;i++){
        if (valueArray[i]===character) {
            charCount += 1; 
        }
    }
    if(charCount>1){
        var newValue=value.replaceAll(".","");
        alert(newValue);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently accomplished this with the following code. This sat in a function that was triggered for each keypress on the field. It might be a bit messy and I'm sure there's a better way, but it works. It also allows someone to enter a "." if they have one selected, since it would replace that selected one:

```
// Function to verify number
function isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

// Function called (below) to get text if it is selected
function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}

// jQuery function on keypress for the textbox
$(".textbox").on("keypress", function (e) {
        var fieldVal = $(this).val();
        if (e.keyCode == 9) return true; // tab
        var keyPressed = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
        if (keyPressed == "." && ((fieldVal.indexOf(".") == -1) || getSelectionText().indexOf(".") > 0)) return true; // decimal places, only allow one
        return (isNumber(keyPressed));
    });
```

EDIT: I should mention, the isNumber() function also checks to verify that the end result is a number. I can post that if you'd like also.

EDIT 2: Modified code block to add the isNumber() function.

Comment: @Tartar I've updated to add the isNumber() function.

Comment: By the way users not typing keys on my calculator, all numbers are buttons so it will be useless for my calculator.

Comment: @Tartar ahhh okay, I misunderstood. You could probably rework the function a bit to trigger on button press and then check the associated button value.

Comment: Yes it is so, it's hard to check dots for me .

Comment: What i want to do is, when a user click the dot button a dot will be write to a text and if user click the dot button more than one no more dots will be write to the text.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but if all you want to do is prevent inserting more decimals, then just check the character and if it's a decimal, return false.

Answer (score 0):

Your (main) problem is this test :

```
if(!replace)
```

When replace is `""`, `!""` is `true`.

Change the test to

```
if (replace==null)
```

(it works for both `undefined` and `null`)

But I don't really see why you need to define a `replaceAll` function when you seem to want

```
var newValue=value.replace(/\./g,"");
```

---

EDIT : If what you want is to replace all dots apart the first one you can do

```
var i=0, newValue=value.replace(/\./g, function(){ return i++ ? "," : "." });
```

(you don't need to count before that, and `i` will be the count of dots)

Comment: Thanks,this fixed the replaceAll problem but my main problem is to allow only one "." to user.

Comment: You mean you want to replace starting from the second one ?

Comment: Yes, only one "." should be allowed.

Comment: @Tartar Is the code I give at end of my answer what you look for ?

Comment: Okay,should i call this function in <body onLoad=""> ?